# Linux Script error with comparing strings

Tags: linux, bash, unix, string-comparison, string-length

i'm trying to take two string input and check if they are equal or not, if not equal then tell the character length. i'm getting not found error after i type two strings, can someone tell what am i doing wrong? i tried using:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while true; do
    echo "Please Enter two name to compare"
    read name_1 name_2
    1=${#name_1}
    2=${#name_2}

    if [ "$name_1" -eq  "$name_2" ] 
    then
      echo "$name_1 and $name_2 are equal"
    else
      echo "$name_1 and $name_2 are not equal"
    fi 
    echo "String 1 length is $(1)"            
    echo "String 2 length is $(2)"

    done
```

Comment: I am getting "command not found" errors related to the 1=${#name_1} and 2=${#name_2} in your script.  What is your exact error message text, please...

Comment: this is the exact error i'm getting `question10: 13: question10: length_1: not found
String 1 length is 
question10: 14: question10: length_2: not found
String 2 length is 
question10: 15: question10: Syntax error: "done" unexpected
`

Answer (score 1):

This one will work exactly as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
echo "Please Enter two name to compare"
read name_1 name_2
one=${#name_1}
two=${#name_2}

if [ "$name_1" = "$name_2" ]
then
  echo "$name_1 and $name_2 are equal"
else
  echo "$name_1 and $name_2 are not equal"
fi 
echo "String 1 length is $one"            
echo "String 2 length is $two"

done
```

Comment: i tried using == but i didn't work im getting error                                `question10: 13: question10: length_1: not found
String 1 length is 
question10: 14: question10: length_2: not found
String 2 length is 
question10: 15: question10: Syntax error: "done" unexpected1`

Comment: Use [[ ]] around your 'if' statement.

Answer (score 1):

Points:

- A user defined variable in `bash` can not start with a digit and so obviously can not only be a digit
- `-eq` does arithmetic comparison; as you are comparing strings use `=` (POSIX) or `==`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.  I used `[[ ]]` around your `if` and changed the variables from `1` and `2` to `x` and `y`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo "Please Enter two name to compare"
    read name_1 name_2
    x=${#name_1}
    y=${#name_2}

    if [[ "$name_1" == "$name_2" ]]
    then
      echo "$name_1 and $name_2 are equal"
    else
      echo "$name_1 and $name_2 are not equal"
    fi
    echo "String 1 length is $x"
    echo "String 2 length is $y"

done
exit
```

Comment: Funny how `[[ "John" -eq "Doe" ]]` is true? I guess you want `=` or `==`

Comment: No, it doesn't compare variable content lengths.